# Missing value Imputation based on regression in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

i want to inpute the missing data based on multivariate imputation, in the below-attached data sets, column A has some missing values, and Column A and Column B have the correlation factor of 0.70. So I want to use a regression kind of realationship so that it will build the relation between Column A and Column B and impute the missing values in Python.

N.B.: I can do it using Mean, median, and mode, but I want to use the relationship from another column to fill the missing value.

How to deal the problem. your solution, please

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
import numpy as np
  

    # assign data of lists.  
    data = {'Date': ['9/19/14', '9/20/14', '9/21/14', '9/21/14','9/19/14', '9/20/14', '9/21/14', '9/21/14','9/19/14', '9/20/14', '9/21/14', '9/21/14', '9/21/14'], 
            'A': [77.13, 39.58, 33.70, np.nan, np.nan,39.66, 64.625, 80.04, np.nan ,np.nan ,19.43, 54.375, 38.41],
            'B': [19.5, 21.61, 22.25, 25.05, 24.20, 23.55, 5.70, 2.675, 2.05,4.06, -0.80, 0.45, -0.90],
            'C':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']}  
      
    # Create DataFrame  
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)  
    df["Date"]= pd.to_datetime(df["Date"]) 
    # Print the output.  
    print(df)
```

Comment: Do what with the correlation? How do we impute a value based on a correlation?

Comment: Yes, based on regression, i want to impute the missing values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
dfreg = df[df['A'].notna()]
dfimp = df[df['A'].isna()]

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor    
regr = MLPRegressor(random_state=1, max_iter=200).fit(dfreg['B'].values.reshape(-1, 1), dfreg['A'])
regr.score(dfreg['B'].values.reshape(-1, 1), dfreg['A'])

regr.predict(dfimp['B'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Note that in the provided data correlation of the A and B columns are very low (less than .05).
For replacing the imputed values with empty cells:

```
s = df[df['A'].isna()]['A'].index
df.loc[s, 'A'] = regr.score(dfreg['B'].values.reshape(-1, 1), dfreg['A'])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How to add the outcome to the original data frame.